# WPF: How to ensure that the format of type-in fields is correct?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, textbox

This question is related to the little red rectangle that appears by itself every time a user types, say, a letter in a field that is supposed to hold numeric values.

[image]

Let's be more specific: In one of my application's fields the user types a floating point value which **must** be multiple of 0.25 (50.00, 74.25, 8.50, 0.75, etc., etc.).

I saw somewhere a custom message that can be displayed next to the red frame.

How do we implement such constraint?

TIA

Comment: You can use ValidationRule and define Validation.ErrorTemplate for texbox. See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the error template for TextBox as your required. Check the following link for more details.

http://www.gonetdotnet.info/posts/wpf-articles/wpf-error-validation-and-display